# Unable to install theme with composer

Tags: magento2, theme, composer

I'm trying to install Alpaca theme following the [documentation](https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-alpaca-theme/blob/master/README.md).

I've created my `composer.json` file under `app/design/frontend/ben/gotheme/composer.json`

```
{
  "name": "ben/gotheme",
  "description": "",
  "type": "magento2-theme",
  "require": {
    "snowdog/theme-frontend-alpaca": "2.19.*",
    "ben/gotheme-front-tools": "*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

My `registration.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/ben/gotheme',
    __DIR__);
```

When I try to install the theme running the following command from mangeto root I get an error:

```
composer require ben/gotheme
```

The error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                                    
Could not find a matching version of package ben/gotheme. Check the package spelling, your 
version constraint and that the package is available in a stabili  ty which matches your minimum-stability (stable).
```

I'm unsure what's going here. Why is composer not finding my package? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you configured your main composer.json to know where to look for your custom package (i.e. probably as a "path" or  "artifact")?  https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#hosting-your-own

Comment: No I have not done this. So I add the path to the theme root as a repository? I'm using paths in this case.

Comment: I believe that you would want to configure your main composer.json by running something like: "composer config repositories.ben path app/design/frontend/ben/gotheme". This should add the relevant path repository to your main composer.json, and allow it to be found when you run "composer require".

Comment: I ended up adding it manually in the `composer.json` and running `composer update`. But, I see it would have been easier to just run `composer require`. Thank you. If you can make that into an answer I will accept.

Comment: I'm glad that it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty narrow understanding of composer, so perhaps someone will add a more comprehensive response.

The issue is that the main composer.json must be configured to look for any custom package that is not hosted in the default packagist.org repository (https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#hosting-your-own)

This can be done by using, e.g. `composer config repositories.ben path app/design/frontend/ben/gotheme`

In this example "repositories.ben" sets "ben" as the repository name. The path should be the path to the directory where your package's composer.json is located. (This could also be a path to a custom module in /vendor).

Running this command will add a repository configuration to the main composer.json, such as in the following example, where it is added to the existing Magento2 repository configuration:

```
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "ben": {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "app/design/frontend/ben/gotheme"
    }
},
```

(It is also fine to edit composer.json directly)

Once the repository is configured, the package will be found when running, e.g. `composer require ben/gotheme`